# Unable to get self generated certificate to work with curl

Tags: curl, certificate, ssl-certificate, bolt-cms, ampps

I am working on a project on my local server ampps.

I have a website using the CMS Bolt. I want to install an extension via the administration.

When I install an extension I get this error:

```
Testing connection to extension server failed: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

I don't know how to get it to make work. I read the documentation about the `curl` problem on Bolt.cm documentation and I read many many post by searching on google.

Comment: Did you self generate the certificate? If so, then that's a normal error. You can bypass it by adding a command line option to cURL which in your case is probably not useful. Otherwise, you could try to get a certificate in a place such as https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: Yes I am using a self generate certificate. What line did I have to add and where to bypass?

Comment: Under Linux, use `man curl` for more info. Look at the `-k` (a.k.a. `--insecure`) command line option. However, if Bolt generates that command line, you'd have to tweak it so it includes that extra option. If I recall, the result is an error message in `stderr` about the fact that it could not verify the certificate. It will still be fully secure. Bonne chance.

Comment: I try the comment line curl -k and curl --insecure and nothing work. Now I have this error: `Testing connection to extension server failed: cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: ‘Applications/AMPPS/extra/etc/openssl/certs/cacert.pem’ CApath: none (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)` Does I have to have a CApath too?

Comment: I'm not too sure why it says that... That's the option you are supposed to use so the certificate is accepted as is. See also:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60750/does-curl-have-a-no-check-certificate-option-like-wget